# What does the "disputed" status of a flag mean?

Tags: support, flagging

What does the "disputed" status of a flag mean?  E.g.

[image]

Does it mean that the moderators couldn't decide whether the flag should be accepted or declined ?  .

Comment: [MSO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275) on the same topic ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It basically means that non mods disagreed on the flag.

In this case, it [was marked as "looks good"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/21044) in the review queue. Which seems correct to me because it's not deletable and can be improved (VLQ is for non salvageable stuff)