# How should I flag link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, flagging, best-practices

I noticed [this link-only answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/807637/145491) and thought I should flag it, but discovered that "link-only" is not in the criteria under the "I am flagging to report this answer as... " "Not an answer" option. Does this mean we should not flag link-only answers, or click the "Not an answer" option, or enter "Link Only" under the "In need of moderator intervention" option?

I thought I would find a answer here or on the mother-meta, and there certainly are related questions such as ["Why was my flag on a 'link-only' answer disputed?"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7193/145491) or ["How to flag link-only answers / what happened to the very low quality flag?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290742/356966), but to my surprise I could not find a simple, clear answer.

Comment: Well it's not really an answer, so probably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the best option in this case is the "not an answer" flag, based on the guidelines [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370). This applies if there is absolutely *no* content in the answer other than the link. As such, the answer you linked falls into this category.

Comment: Agreed. Note that the "standard flags" put a post into a review queue which can be accessed by lots of high-reputation users, while the "in need of moderator intervention" flags are only seen by the six diamond moderators.